# IIS FTP powershell site creation fails with pipeline error

Tags: iis, windows-7, ftp

When I run the following line Power shell throws a Pipeline has been stopped exception on the `New-WebFtpSite` command.

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerRole /featurename:IIS-FTPServer
New-WebFtpSite -Name 'Default Ftp Site' -Port '21'
```

I can't seem to get around the exception. Is there a better way of setting up an FTP server on Windows 7 powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the feature `IIS-FTPSvc` along with the other already enabled features solved my problem.

Final command looks like the following, no need for the cmd /c stuff:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerRole /featurename:IIS-FTPServer /featurename:IIS-FTPSvc
```

Comment: I recommended this to you.  If you read the exact command from the 2nd to last post on that link I sent you to it has the exact command you've got here with the cmd /c switch and a WAIT.  You could probably get by without the cmd section, but I did point you to the exact command already???

Comment: You said to use the cmd /c switch which didn't solve my problem. By posting my own answer others don't have to hunt around if someone comes across a similar issue.

Comment: I could have posted the first command from the site I referenced but I wanted people to see the process the other guy went through so they knew,and no I didn't say JUST to use the cmd /c switch I said use his command on the 2nd to last post which is exactly what you posted word for word.

Answer (score 0):

Start by using the *cmd /c* switch before your first dism command.  See [this post](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/14007.aspx) (2nd to last comment at the very bottom) for a better formatted command than the current one you're using.

Then, use this command for the FTP site creation:

```
New-WebFtpSite -Name testFtpSite -Port 21 -PhysicalPath c:\test -HostHeader mySite -IPAddress 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: By just adding `cmd /c START /WAIT` before the DISM command it is still throwing a pipeline error when I get to the New-WebFtpSite command..